# Proper way of Initializing dictionary with list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to  construct a dictionary whose values are lists in the example code below why all the values are not coming for **US & UK**

```
cities = {'San Francisco': 'US', 'London': 'UK',
          'Manchester': 'UK', 'Paris': 'France',
          'Los Angeles': 'US', 'Seoul': 'Korea'}

a = {}

for item, key in cities.items():
    a[key] = [item]

print(a)
```

Current Output

```
{'US': ['Los Angeles'], 'UK': ['Manchester'], 'France': ['Paris'], 'Korea': ['Seoul']}
```

Expected Output

```
{'US': ['San Francisco', 'Los Angeles'], 'UK': ['London', 'Manchester'], 'France': ['Paris'], 'Korea': ['Seoul']}
```

Comment: Where exactly do you think you add to any existing list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use `.setdefault` method of `dict` for this task as follows

```
cities = {'San Francisco': 'US', 'London': 'UK',
          'Manchester': 'UK', 'Paris': 'France',
          'Los Angeles': 'US', 'Seoul': 'Korea'}

a = {}

for item, key in cities.items():
    a.setdefault(key,[]).append(item)

print(a)
```

output

```
{'US': ['San Francisco', 'Los Angeles'], 'UK': ['London', 'Manchester'], 'France': ['Paris'], 'Korea': ['Seoul']}
```

Explanation: If `a` does not already have `key` then put `[]` (empty `list`). Add `item` at end of list which is under `key`.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is overriding the value for each key every time you encounter it. To fix this, check if there's an existing element, and if so, append instead of overwrite.

```py
cities = {'San Francisco': 'US', 'London': 'UK',
          'Manchester': 'UK', 'Paris': 'France',
          'Los Angeles': 'US', 'Seoul': 'Korea'}

a = {}

for item, key in cities.items():
    if key not in a:
        a[key] = [item]
    else:
        a[key].append(item)

print(a)
```